# Handling Replicate Data in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to plot a scatter plot of some data over time with std deviation as error bars. And I have triplicate measurements for each time point for two different samples A and B.

```
Date A1 A2 A3 B1 B2 B3
1/1/17 4 5 6 2 3 4
1/2/17 6 7 8 5 6 4
```

So I am importing the data like this:

```
import pandas as pd
columns = ['Date', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3']
dat = pd.read_csv('data', sep='\t', names=columns)
```

How then can i combine the replicate columns so that I can calculate standard deviation and then plot? I was thinking of renaming the A and B columns so they are the same and can then be combined?

Comment: How do you want them combined? Unless you tell us how you want it, we can't know what you want...

Comment: Agreed, are you asking to put all the A's in a single column and all the B's in another? Or are you asking something different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have to admit, I don't really get what you want, but I thought this was cool.

- Transpose because I want to run `groupby`/`agg` but it isn't implemented yet on columns
- Group by the first character of the column name then find `mean` and `std`
- Use that to plot stuff with error bars.

---

```
d = df.T.groupby(lambda x: x[0]).agg(['mean', 'std']).T
d.xs('mean', level=1).plot.bar(yerr=d.xs('std', level=1))
```

Or same idea with slightly different path

```
d = df.T.groupby(lambda x: x[0]).agg(['mean', 'std']).stack(0).unstack(0)
d['mean'].plot.bar(yerr=d['std'])
```

[image]

---

Otherwise, we could do a single reduction

```
df.groupby(lambda x: x[0], 1).mean()

        A  B
Date        
1/1/17  5  3
1/2/17  7  5
```

Comment: It certainly is!

Comment: @piRSquared perfect this is exactly what I was looking for, thanks.